# Permission Stuck to read-only in my second Disk

Tags: permissions, mount

I was doing dual boot but I decided to delete both Windows and Ubuntu and reinstall only Ubuntu

Since I've done that the permission on my second HDD have changed to read-only and no matter what command iIve thrown at it kept like that so can you guys help me?

Actually there is one that I tried and almost worked

```
sudo mount -o remount,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw /dev/sda2
```

but when I went to create a file it didn't and I got this error:

> [image: Error while creating directory a]

I'm trying to learn more about the command but I'm still a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to learn about linux permissions. By default, a user can only write in his home folder, or in folders of removable drives mounted automatically under /media/.

Make sure the second volume is automatically mounted on startup. This can be set using the utility "Disks", or by manually editing the configuration file `/etc/fstab` yourself.

Then, you will need to change owners and/or permissions to what is desired. You can change the owner of the entire second drive if you wish that a single user can write to it. If there are multiple users, then you can create separate directories for each user and change the owners of each of them. To change owners, use the `chown` command:

```
sudo chown newuser:newuser /path/to/folder
```

will change both user and group of the folder `/path/to/folder` to user `newuser` and his group.